# filtrar datos con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy tratando de comparar dos columnas de un data frame, es decir, un merge para verificar si un elemento de una columna aparece en otra columna del mismo data frame y que finalmente me filtre el nombre y la matrícula (por el momento). Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

1. Primero cargo los archivos de Excel y los guardo en un dataframe individual respectivamente
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Posteriormente concateno las columnas que me interesa analizar en un solo dataframe, las columnas que me interesa analizar o hacer el merge, es decir si un elemento de la columna Matricula (del archivo 'Alertas Tempranas 2 Noviembre.xlsx') aparece en la columna MAT.(del archivo 'Nac AP Alumnos S1 M11 2023.xlsx')

```py
df_cnci = pd.concat([df_Alertas['Matricula'],df_Nac[['NOMBRE','MAT.']]],axis=1)
```

3. Después, en las siguientes dos líneas convierto las columnas a string y convierto las columnas que me interesa analizar a listas para hacer el merge o intersección

```py
df_cnci =df_cnci.astype({'Matricula': "string", 'NOMBRE': "string",'MAT.': "string"})
l_matricula = df_cnci['Matricula'].tolist()
l_MAT = df_cnci['MAT.'].tolist()
```

4. Finalmente hago la intersección o cruce con:

```py
l_mergeMAT = list(set(l_matricula) & set(l_MAT))
```

5. Ahora bien, en las siguientes líneas lo que hago es hacer el filtro a partir de las matriculas que me arrojó el merge o la intersección, mi duda es ¿Cómo puedo recorrer la lista resultante de la intersección? es decir, en

```py
l_mergeMAT # [Aquí debe de ir la posición de cada matricula, pero no sé cómo hacerlo dinámicamente]
df_cnci = df_cnci.loc[df_cnci['MAT.'] == l_mergeMAT[10]] 
df_cnci[['NOMBRE','MAT.']]
```

pd: lo que me interesa que imprima son las columnas 'NOMBRE' y 'MAT.' del archivo Nac AP Alumnos S1 M11 2023.xlsx

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo optimizar esta linea de código en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/608504/como-puedo-optimizar-esta-linea-de-c%c3%b3digo-en-python)