# ¿Como puedo optimizar esta linea de código en python?

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```py
df_cnci = df_cnci[df_cnci['MAT.'] == i for i in l_mergeMAT]
df_cnci[['NOMBRE','MAT.']]
```

Lo que quiero realizar es que en la parte del for me obtenga el valor de la lista `l_mergeMAT` en cada iteración y después realizar el filtro de mi dataframe para finalmente mostrarlo, pero me marca error. He investigado y esto se conoce como expresión generadora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejando de lado por el momento el error de sintaxis, ten en cuenta que tal como lo planteas, cada filtro booleano generaría un nuevo DataFrame, uno por cada valor contenido en la lista.

Partamos de un ejemplo simplificado:

```
import pandas as pd


df_cnci = pd.DataFrame({"NOMBRE": ("Nombre_1", "Nombre_2", "Nombre_3", "Nombre_4", "Nombre_5"),
                        "MAT.": ("Mat_A", "Mat_B", "Mat_C", "Mat_B", "Mat_A")
                       }, index=None)

l_mergeMAT = ["Mat_A", "Mat_B"]
```

Si funcionara lo que intentas seria algo similar a:

```
for mat in l_mergeMAT:
    print(f'{"=" * 40}\nMat. == {mat}\n{"=" * 40}')
    print(df_cnci[df_cnci["MAT."] == mat])
```

---

```
========================================
Mat. == Mat_A
========================================
    NOMBRE   MAT.
0  Nombre_1  Mat_A
4  Nombre_5  Mat_A
========================================
Mat. == Mat_B
========================================
     NOMBRE   MAT.
1  Nombre_2  Mat_B
3  Nombre_4  Mat_B
```

Y si, podrias generar una lista de dataframes que contuviera el resultado de cada filtro booleano:

```
filt_list = [df_cnci[df_cnci["MAT."] == mat] for mat in l_mergeMAT]
```

Pero creo que no es lo que buscas, lo que creo que quieres es filtrar todas las filas del dataframe cuyo valor de su columna `MAT.` esta en la lista. Para ello puedes usar `pandas.Series.isin` para crear el filtro booleano y luego aplicarlo sobre el dataframe:

```
df_cnci[df_cnci["MAT."].isin(l_mergeMAT)]
```

O usar `pandas.DataFrame.query`:

```
df_cnci.query("`MAT.` in @l_mergeMAT")
```

o también:

```
df_cnci.query("`MAT.` == @l_mergeMAT")
```

Las tres generan:

```
      NOMBRE     MAT.
0   Nombre_1    Mat_A
1   Nombre_2    Mat_B
3   Nombre_4    Mat_B
4   Nombre_5    Mat_A
```